# angular validation check for uniqueness

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering is there a way how to check value for uniqueness using *poor angular validation*, without addition directives and plugins.

For example let's say that I have an array in scope:

```
$scope.colors = ['red', 'green', 'black', 'grey'];
```

and I want to check if entered value doesn't exist in there.

Here is an input

```
 <input name="color" type="text" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="selectedColor" required=""/>
```

I know that angular provides some nice directive such a *ng-minlength* or *ng-pattern*, but maybe somehow I will be able to call a function from controller where I can check value for uniqueness?

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jYSL1Mff6LUxKho23Akp?p=preview)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `ng-change="checkIfUnique(selectedColor)"`... but on its own it won't invalidate the ngmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<input name="color" ng-change="checkUnique()" type="text" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="selectedColor" required=""/>
```

and:

```
  $scope.colors = ['red', 'green', 'black', 'grey'];

  $scope.checkUnique = function(){
    if($scope.colors.indexOf($scope.selectedColor) != -1){
        console.log($scope.colors.indexOf('black'));  // it means it is already present in the array
    }
  }
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-pattern and replace the pattern according to your need

```
 <input type="text" ng-minlength="3" ng-pattern="'('+colors.join(')|(')+')'" ng-model="selectedColor" required=""/>
```